# How to create proper Heart icon line in Sketch?

Tags: vector, shapes, sketch-app

I have been moved from Illustrator to Sketch recently, but I don't understand how pathfinder work in Sketch very much.

I try to create some line heart icon with + in it like this (this was created by illustrator).

[image: heart icon]

I can create just a line in Sketch but after that I got confuse with "subtract" function in Sketch and it got weird result. For example there are some twisted line and can not subtract properly.

[image: heart icon2]

I try to search for how to, but I can not find it anywhere. For now I just created this icon in Illustrator and copied to Sketch. But I want to know how to create in Sketch for future reference.

Answer (score 7):

First, create rect with no fill and thick borders.
Enable edit mode and select two corners, make the radius about 100.
[image]

Rotate the rect by 45 degrees
[image]

Duplicate the rect by pressing <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. Flip it horizontally and place so that lower corner will be place at the same position.
[image]

Now, let's create the cross.
Create rect with width the same as heart's border. And border of the rect should be white color and outside.
[image]

Duplicate the rect and rotate it to horizontal position.
[image]

Select the two rects and press the Union icon on toolbar.
[image]

Finally place the cross above the heart.
[image]

**You can download the Sketch file [here](http://ge.tt/92T2dKb2)**